# How can i send a message to a Chat group in Teams using powershell?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have microsoft teams and when i click on Chart in the left hand side  it brings up
all the people and groups .. There is a group called Dev Group.

I would like to be able to send a message to that group from powershell.
How can i send a message to that group using powershell ?
Are there any steps or configuration i need to do first ?

Comment: This looks promising. https://www.powershellcenter.com/2022/07/15/new-mgchat/

Comment: In addition to the below answer you can send messages to Teams channels from PowerShell Microsoft Graph API calls. Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell

Answer (score 1):

Currently, 2023-12, you can not send messages to MSTeams **chat**, but you can send messages to MSTeams **team channel**.

---

There is [Incoming WebHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook) feature - a special secret public URL, which can be generated for **team channel** and can be used to send messages to this **team channel**, not **chat**.

Minimal example:

```
$text = 'Hello there!'
$webhookUrl = 'https://???.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/???/IncomingWebhook/???/???'

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $webhookUrl -Body (@{text = $text} | ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType 'application/json'
```

---

See [Incoming WebHook page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook) to find out more.